# Fn-keys stopped working on a Lenovo Thinkpad Edge

Tags: suspend, brightness, lenovo, thinkpad, volume-control

I'm running 12.04 on a Lenovo ThinkPad Edge. I'm having these possibly related issues with things that worked perfectly when I installed Ubuntu:

1. Most of the Fn-keys worked seamlessly after I freshly installed Ubuntu, most importantly <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>/<kbd>F2</kbd>/<kbd>F3</kbd> for mute/volume control and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>/<kbd>F8</kbd> for brightness. Recently they stopped working all together and the Fn-button does nothing at all.
2. When I close the lid on the laptop the computer doesn't go to suspend mode like it used to (and still is set to do), it just goes on running and doesn't register when I close the lid.

I noticed these two things within the same day. I haven't changed any settings that relates to these things but I've recently installed recommend updates.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. It helped me.
Maybe it would be better if you put it into separate answer and mark it as solved. It would be easier to see ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a BIOS issue with Thinkpad Edge with no known permanent solution. [See this](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-Edge-S-series/Hotkeys-no-longer-working-ThinkPad-Edge-14-Windows-7/td-p/323077) - the solutions discussed all turn out to be temporary.

Removing and reinserting the battery (as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/39343/76766)) is the only fix but it only works temporary. Every once in a while the FN keys stop working again and I have to remove and reinsert the battery. Booting and rebooting seems to increase the frequency of when the bug happens so I avoid that by only suspending and hibernating my computer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and ended up downloading/installing the updated HotKeys update on the Lenovo site (guvu26ew.exe).  Once I did that, all of my Function keys worked fine.  It also fixed my wireless problem - since I was being told that no wireless connections were in range. . . Once I could get the function keys to work, I could turn on the Master Radio switch and also turn on the individual wireless and bluetooth radios.  Now, all is fine.  Good luck.

Comment: How did you run an *.exe file on Ubuntu? Or did you install it with Windows and it ran a firmware update?

Comment: http://support.lenovo.com/ca/fr/downloads/ds031814, doesn't appear to be firmware.